# Comma in SELECT AS statement meaning

Tags: sql, pivot

The following query does a pivot

```
create table temp
(
  id int,
  teamid int,
  userid int,
  elementid int,
  phaseid int,
  effort decimal(10, 5)
)

insert into temp values (1,1,1,3,5,6.74)
insert into temp values (2,1,1,3,6,8.25)
insert into temp values (3,1,1,4,1,2.23)
insert into temp values (4,1,1,4,5,6.8)
insert into temp values (5,1,1,4,6,1.5)

select elementid
  , [1] as phaseid1
  , [5] as phaseid5
  , [6] as phaseid6
from
(
  select elementid, phaseid, effort
  from temp
) x
pivot
(
  max(effort)
  for phaseid in([1], [5], [6])
)p
```

I don't understand what this part of the query is doing.  Can someone explain?

```
select elementid
  , [1] as phaseid1
  , [5] as phaseid5
  , [6] as phaseid6
```

Comment: It's renaming the output columns. That snippet doesn't "work" without the pivot portion though. The derived table is just selecting the few columns relevant for the pivot operation.

Comment: yea but I still don't get it what is [1] as phaseid1 @shawnt00

Comment: The pivot creates its output based on the column values. Since those are not normally valid column names you need to use the square brackets.

Comment: Can you tag the DBMS you're using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first SELECT portion of the pivot query is basically indicating which columns you want within your resultant pivot table.
The values of the rows within the column that you choose to pivot by (in this case the phaseid) become the column names in the output table, which then contains then values that you pull in to populate the new columns (effort).

In this example the row values that become column names are integers, and you can't start a column name with a number generally (in MS SQL Server anyway), and the way to indicate a column name or other thing with unconventional naming is to surround it in square brackets. The AS command lets you either alias or rename columns.

So here you are selecting the row values that you want to become columns and renaming them into useful names that makes the pivoted table clear, along with the elementid column and its rows that these pivoted values relate to.

Hope that makes sense